# stop Listview from capturing mouse scroll inside ScrollViewer in XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, win-universal-app, scrollviewer

Hello I'm making UWP app, where on one of the pages I want a website like experience, meaning a long scroll on the page.

I have a Listview inside a pivot on the page.

It looks something like this.

```
<ScrollViewer
        x:Name="scrollViewer"
        ManipulationMode="All"
        ScrollViewer.IsVerticalScrollChainingEnabled="True"
        VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <RelativePanel>
            <Image />
    <Pivot>
        <Listview />
    </Pivot>
    <Other stuff /> 
    </RelativePanel>
```

Now my problem is that, the mouse scroll works fine when im holding the mouse over any object except the listview, as soon as the mouse is over the listview the scroll dont work.

I have tried creating a custom ListView Style like this but that dont work.

```
<Style
            x:Key="NoScrollListViewStyle"
            TargetType="ListView">
            <Setter
                Property="IsTabStop"
                Value="False" />
            <Setter
                Property="TabNavigation"
                Value="Once" />
            <Setter
                Property="IsSwipeEnabled"
                Value="False" />
            <Setter
                Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility"
                Value="Disabled" />
            <Setter
                Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility"
                Value="Disabled" />
            <Setter
                Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode"
                Value="Disabled" />
            <Setter
                Property="ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled"
                Value="False" />
            <Setter
                Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode"
                Value="Disabled" />
            <Setter
                Property="ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled"
                Value="False" />
            <Setter
                Property="ScrollViewer.ZoomMode"
                Value="Disabled" />
            <Setter
                Property="ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled"
                Value="False" />
            <Setter
                Property="ScrollViewer.BringIntoViewOnFocusChange"
                Value="True" />
            <Setter
                Property="ItemContainerTransitions">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <TransitionCollection>
                        <AddDeleteThemeTransition />
                        <ContentThemeTransition />
                        <ReorderThemeTransition />
                        <EntranceThemeTransition
                            IsStaggeringEnabled="False" />
                    </TransitionCollection>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter
                Property="ItemsPanel">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <ItemsStackPanel
                            Orientation="Vertical" />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter
                Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate
                        TargetType="ListView">
                        <Border
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <ScrollViewer
                                x:Name="ScrollViewer"
                                AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"
                                BringIntoViewOnFocusChange="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.BringIntoViewOnFocusChange}"
                                HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled"
                                HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                                IsHorizontalRailEnabled="False"
                                IsHorizontalScrollChainingEnabled="False"
                                IsVerticalScrollChainingEnabled="False"
                                IsVerticalRailEnabled="False"
                                IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="False"
                                TabNavigation="{TemplateBinding TabNavigation}"
                                VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                                VerticalScrollMode="Disabled"
                                ZoomMode="Disabled">
                                <ItemsPresenter
                                    FooterTransitions="{TemplateBinding FooterTransitions}"
                                    FooterTemplate="{TemplateBinding FooterTemplate}"
                                    Footer="{TemplateBinding Footer}"
                                    HeaderTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}"
                                    Header="{TemplateBinding Header}"
                                    HeaderTransitions="{TemplateBinding HeaderTransitions}"
                                    Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" />
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On solution that cross my mind is to capture `PointerWheelChanged` event and move `ScrollView`:

```
   private void ListView_PointerWheelChanged(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
     ScrollView.ScrollToVerticalOffset(ScrollView.VerticalOffset - e.GetCurrentPoint(ScrollView).Properties.MouseWheelDelta);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you that does work if i do - instead of plus. mainscrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(mainscrollViewer.VerticalOffset - e.GetCurrentPoint(mainscrollViewer).Properties.MouseWheelDelta);